# How to combine cells from non - adjacent columns row wise into a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write the code to combine the values of the two columns in a range and write it to a cell on next sheet in excel using vba

After merging the columns to unique values the ranges are as shown in the image

The columns A and E are non adjacent columns.
I want the result on next sheet in a cell as := BCCH NL:968,TCHNL:961

I am new to vba.

I had used the below code for merging cells

```
Sub MergeAdjacentCell()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim Rng As range, xCell As range
Dim WorkRng As range
Dim xTitleId As String
Dim xRows As Integer
Dim i As Byte
Dim j As Byte

Set WorkRng = range("A1:A" & 6 & ",E1:E" & 6)
WorkRng.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count

For Each Rng In WorkRng.Columns

    For i = 1 To xRows - 1

        For j = i + 1 To xRows

            If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then

                Exit For

            End If

        Next

        WorkRng.Parent.range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge

        i = j - 1

    Next

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

i tried some things out but couldn't find the ways to do it.
Please Help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest you add whatever you have tried with VBA also, add an image how the desired result should look like.

Comment: Hi Naresh, I want it for a range eg.A1:A6 to E1:E6 ,then it should combine each cell of two columns row wise –

Comment: i have attached the code used for merging the cells in adjacent columns to unique values

Comment: I am bit confused with the code, I spppose you need just mege the code from two cells and result into another cell. Why are you running two loops?

Comment: If it's just A & ": & E then you can use formula `=A1 & ":" & E1`, I might be wrong because I think the I missing the part of unique

Comment: Yes the data must be unique

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to do this using VBA:

I've just created this Excel sheet:

```
     A   B   C   D
   --- --- --- ---
1 | AA           1
2 | BB           2
```

And in another cell, I've typed this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A1:D2)
```

Meaning:

```
TEXTJOIN : concatenate text
";"      : delimiter
TRUE     : omit empty cells
```

The result is:

```
AA;1;BB;2
```

In case you want to different delimiters (a ":" and a comma), you can use a helper column (like column "E"), where you use `=TEXTJOIN'(":",TRUE, A1:D1)` and afterwards use a `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,E1:E10)`.

Comment: But the above will take columns B and C also. In actual data i have some other data in between so i want to take only two adjacent columns

Comment: Then it's even easier: instead of `TEXTJOIN()` of an entire range, just do it for the cells you want to join, like `=TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,A1,D1)`.

Comment: Hi i have excel 2013 and textjoin function doesnt work there is there any alternative?